# how supply firefox addon UUID in xpi?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a firefox addon, and when I wanted to fix it I see that I can upload a new version. so I accessed addons builder at **builder.addons.mozilla.org** and write the new code and download it as xpi file. then back to my addon and try to upload the new xpi addon as a new version. but the problem that an error says "UUID doesn't match add-on" !

how can I write UUID in my code to match with my addon.

And how can I remove one of my developed addons ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just got similar issue (an existing addon that's developed without SDK, and then a new version that's build by SDK: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), and got direct feedback from amo editors.

Replace the id field in package.json with the original id in the existing addon's install.rdf. 
NOTE: it should be the `<em:id>` field on top level, instead of the id for Firefox within the `<em:targetApplication>` part. Then the id in the generated xpi file will agree with the old version.

Do NOT delete the existing versions and create a new addon, as I did. It cause trouble in their review process.

Comment: replacing the ID with the one found in the install.rdf worked excellent. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

See https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?p=8880 which matches your question almost exactly - there is no good solution. The Add-on Builder will randomly generate a new identifier for each new extension, as far as I know it doesn't allow changing the identifier. You can change the `install.rdf` file manually in the extension generated by the builder as explained in the forum but that's rather complicated. The alternative is to use the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) and to package the extension locally, on your own computer. In addition to the files visible in the builder the Add-on SDK expects a `package.json` file that stores the extension ID among other things.